# npm config set cache <PATH> --global is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Every time, when I run npm, in project folder creating a new folder - **UsersProfessionalAppDataRoamingnpm-cache**. I think, this is a folder for npm cache.
I'm runned `npm config set cache C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache --global` before that.

Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap a path into `"` like this:

```
npm config set cache "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global
```